# Reading line of integers into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop, std

Please have a look at the following code

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter numbers (-1 to stop entering; -2 to exit)" << endl;

    while(cin>>enterNumber)
    {
     numbers.push_back(enterNumber);
    }


    for(size_t size=0;size<numbers.size();size++)
    {
        cout << numbers[size] << endl;
    }
}
```

What  I am trying to do here is something like this

1. Type list of numbers (ex: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 11)
2. Read all of them into the vector
3. Print them

In here, when I hit enter, nothing is happening! Seems like the loops didn't exit. How to print the values when I hit the enter?

**UPDATE**

I edited the code as advises given in answers.

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter numbers (-1 to stop entering; -2 to exit)" << endl;

    std::string line;
getline(std::cin, line);
std::istringstream iss(line);
while (iss >> enterNumber)
{
    numbers.push_back(enterNumber);
}


    for(size_t size=0;size<numbers.size();size++)
    {
        cout << numbers[size] << endl;
    }
}
```

but it gives another error now

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/yohan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Excersice 6'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/excersice_6.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/yohan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Excersice 6'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/Multiple.o.d
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/Multiple.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/Multiple.o Multiple.cpp
Multiple.cpp: In function `int main()':
Multiple.cpp:22: error: variable `std::istringstream iss' has initializer but incomplete type
Multiple.cpp:60:3: warning: no newline at end of file
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/Multiple.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:78: recipe for target `build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/Multiple.o' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/yohan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Excersice 6'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:61: recipe for target `.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/yohan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Excersice 6'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target `.build-impl' failed


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

Comment: Enter is just more whitespace. Enter EOF or something invalid. Even better, if you're already doing it like this, use `std::copy` to copy the inputs to the vector. Incorporating your special inputs will take more work than just `while (cin>>...)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Read in a line from cin into a string using [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).  Then put that string into an `istringstream`.  Then read from that `istringstream` in place of where you're using `cin` now.

```
std::string line;
getline(std::cin, line);
std::istringstream iss(line);
while (iss >> enterNumber)
{
    numbers.push_back(enterNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But it is giving the error "Multiple.cpp:22: error: variable `std::istringstream iss' has initializer but incomplete type"

Comment: @Sepala: `#include <sstream>`

Comment: small EXTRA question. Does C++ convert types automatically? Then why conversion methods are there like static_cast<double> etc?

Comment: @Sepala: The question may be small, but the answer, the thorough answer, is not so small.  Please create a separate post if you have a separate question.

Comment: What does `iss >> enterNumber` return? Why can we use it as a condition for the while loop?

Comment: @AnnaVopureta: It returns a reference to the stream (`iss`, in this case). And since `iss` is an object of type `istringstream`, which is derived from `basic_ios`, it has a conversion operator to bool (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). This operator will return true as long as `iss` is in a good state, which it won't be if the read operation fails, for whatever reason. So the condition is basically, "as long as we are successfully reading from the stream".

Comment: I understand the intuition, I just don't get why exactly it works (why does the boolean value turn to false when the read operation fails and otherwise it's true). The return type of the expression in the while loop is whatever the >> operator returns right? If you go look up the documentation for isstream >> operator, you will see that it returns false when the read is successful, otherwise it returns a non-zero value (which gets mapped to boolean true). This is the reverse of what we need, yet the code works. What am I missing?

Comment: When the operation fails, it puts `iss` in a fail state, either setting badbit, or failbit (members of basic_ios), depending upon why the operation failed. When one of these bits is set, that causes the member function `fail()` to return true. And the boolean conversion operator is basically defined to return the inverse of what `fail()` returns. In other words, it's defined something like this `operator bool() { return !fail(); }`.

Comment: @AnnaVopureta: *"If you go look up the documentation for isstream >> operator, you will see that it returns false when the read is successful"* -- Where did you read this?