# Read external file and assign variables in xml-like input

Tags: c++

In a file which has an xml like format (but is not xml)

```
 <mgrwt event="1">
<rscale>  1 1234</rscale>
<asrwt>0 4234</asrwt>
<pdfrwt beam="1">  1        2 0.11790045E+00 0.22210436E+03</pdfrwt>
<pdfrwt beam="2">  1       -2 0.92962177E-02 0.22210436E+03</pdfrwt>
<totfact> 0.34727485E+01</totfact>
<matchscale> 0.10000000E+11 0.41999999E+02 0.61496031E+02</matchscale>
</mgrwt>
```

I would like with C++ to read in the file (this I know ;-) block-by block , and then assign variables to sub-components of each block,  - I know for example that all numbers  in

```
 <pdfrwt beam="1">  1        2 0.11790045E+00 0.22210436E+03</pdfrwt>
```

ie  `1        2 0.11790045E+00 0.22210436E+03` are always numbers, and never string,so question is , how can I strip/read from each line in each block the separated-by-space numbers ?

I also tried this [Read input numbers separated by spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096719/read-input-numbers-separated-by-spaces) but could not help me..

thanks

Comment: Perhaps look at a C++ SAX parser: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11085/Parsing-XML-using-a-C-wrapper-for-SAX2

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading line by line and using `std::istringstream` to parse the string.
For example, you could find out where the start of the number is by searching for the first `>`.
Either advance the stringstream by this amount or ...

Create a substring contain all the text before the '<'.
Create an `istringstream` using this substring.
Then try something like:

```
unsigned int first, second;
double third, fourth;
string_stream >> first >> second >> third >> fourth;
```

Comment: Hmm.... Well, let me put it another way - What would be the equivalent in C++ to count for the bash command for example

    while read line; do;    cat line | grep -F "> " '{print $2}'; 
       
for example ? How can I strip the line ? Can you give me a working example ?

Comment: And you can't use `std::getline` to read from a file?  Try searching SO for *c++ reading file*.