# passing on inputs to an exe file using c++

Tags: c++, process, io, console

lets say we have a `cal.exe` file (a simple addition calculator programmed programmed in c++).
lets say that the console output screen first displays `enter the first number:` and waits for the user to input an integer value. I am willing to create a c++ program that would "pass on" the required value to the running process (cal.exe) as an input (playing the role of a user). I would also like to have the output from the `cal.exe` file to be displayed and interpreted by my program.

I havent got the slightest idea how to proceed with this. Is there any open source library that would help me accomplish this? If there is, could you name a few?

I have just learned object oriented programming in c++ last year in my school and I am not used to these kind of stuff in programming; so please excuse me if this question is silly.

## update:

lets consider 2 processes a.exe and b.exe running. could you tell me a possible way to program b.exe which provides a integer input to a.exe (a console process) as if it was from the user?

Comment: You can read a console input using [`cin`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096719/read-input-numbers-separated-by-spaces). To print on the console, you can use `cout` for example.

Comment: excuse me for that spelling mistake

Comment: Oh, you mean [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Main_IPC_methods)? There's also this [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372198/best-way-for-interprocess-communication-in-c).

Comment: yes; could you refer any library file I could use to achieve this?

Comment: @user3633270 For a library, check the second link in my previous comment. To know more about all the options, check the first link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by accepting command line arguments.something like this

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

```
enter code here
return 0;
```

}

Where,
First argument to main function (argc) refers to the number of arguments being passed to the program at run-time. 
Second (char *argv[] )refers to a string containing the arguments that are passed (char * is treated as String also ).

Argument names may vary as per the user specifications.

For details Refer:
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/

And for nesting of programs you can use system("name of child program goes here") Function under stdlib.h.

For details Refer:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

Comment: This only works when one executable launches another, and all data must be passed when the second executable is launched.

Comment: You may want to search for "linux expect utility." It is a standalone program with a scripting language used for these kinds of problems.